# Best practice for using f-keys in Emacs term-mode

Tags: emacs, keyboard, key-bindings

I've been looking around for a canonical way to use f-keys in Emacs term-mode, as I'm running a console application that requires them.

Is there already a package that provides this functionality?

I wrote the following to map the f-keys, but this seems like a suboptimal solution:

```el
(defvar f-key-defs
  (let ((fkeys nil))
    (dotimes (i 12)
      (push (cons (intern (concat "f" (int-to-string (1+ i))))
                  (format "\e[%d~" (+ i (if (> i 4) 12 11))))
            fkeys))
    fkeys))

(defun send-f-key ()
  "Send an f-key escape sequence to the sub-process."
  (interactive)
  (term-send-raw-string (alist-get last-input-event f-key-defs)))

(dotimes (i 12)
  (define-key term-raw-map
    (vector (intern (concat "f" (int-to-string (1+ i))))
    #'send-f-key))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look very suboptimal to me (I tweaked your code to use `dotimes` and `term-send-raw-string`).  And it probably makes sense to offer this feature by default, so I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request this new feature (including your code as a possible solution).

Comment: Thanks; while I’m a seasoned emacs user at this point, I’m entirely new to making contributions. Do I need to sign a GNU copyleft agreement or something in order for the code to be accepted?

Comment: and… how should I attribute you when reporting the improved solution?

Comment: We'll cross this bridge when we get there.